# In devise, how do you redirect the user back to a non-app url where they came from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, single-sign-on

Situation: I am building a Rails app that will serve as a central authentication system for a couple of in-house applications.  The app will SSO into these other applications.

So, the path of the user will be https://site-a.com, which will redirect to https://site-b.com (this is the one running Rails w/ Devise and Pundit).  The user will authenticate there.

I need to take that user back to https://site-a.com.

Everything I've seen with Devise is that it can redirect, but only to routes within the application.

Please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise can redirect the user to anywhere after they signs in.

The straightforward way to do that is override the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    "http://site-a.com/"
  end
end
```

For more information about `after_sign_in_path_for`, please see [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

If you have not yet have a clear idea about how to build a SSO system with Devise, you might want to take a look on this article: [Multiple Applications with Devise, Omniauth and Single Sign On](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/).

Comment: Thanks for this. This worked.  Along with devise's authenticated / unauthenticated methods, I'm able to do some really nice routing!